# babel problems: "Unknown option `danish'"

Tags: errors, babel

have problems with the babel options. I use Texmaker and:

```
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
```

and get this failure:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `danish'. Either you misspelled it
```

What to do?

ok, I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\author{test}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is an example
\end{document}
```

and I got that:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.4.26) 26 APR 2014 19:42
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**skanbelon.tex
(./skanbelon.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def
File: latin1.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
! Package babel Error: Unknow option `danish'. Either you misspelled it
(babel) or the language definition file danish.ldf was not found
.
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.293 \ProcessOptions*
Valid options are: shorthands=..., KeepShorthandsActive,
activeacute, activegrave, noconfigs, safe=, main=, math=
headfoot=, strings=, config=, or a language name.
! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.326 ...ry to proceed from here, type x to quit.}
You need to specify a language, either as a global option
or as an optional argument to the \usepackage command;
You shouldn't try to proceed from here, type x to quit.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty
Package: makeidx 2000/03/29 v1.0m Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count99
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen112
\Gin@req@width=\dimen113
)
! LaTeX Error: File `lmodern.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.10 \usepackage
{kpfonts}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1796 strings out of 495031
21907 string characters out of 6181531
72089 words of memory out of 5000000
5027 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
27i,0n,24p,241b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I use Linux Mint Cinammon Petra 16 and have installed LaTeX so:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Ok, i tried this at the very beginning:
    sudo apt-get install texlive-base

And after that I intalled texlive-full

Thanks for the useful solutions (see answers).

SOLUTION:

```
sudo apt-get install update
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Create a small example file which shows the error. I have no problem with TeXLive (up-to-date) and option `danish`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek While you might be right in that the solution could be the same, ``"Unknown option `danish'"`` as a possible duplicate of ``"Unknown option `francais'"`` sounds geographically and culturally wrong ;)

Comment: you should update your TeX distribution. You have version 3.9f of babel but the current one is 3.9k from 2014/03/24

Comment: @Christian You're partly right; but the problem is almost surely the same: probably the OP is using a TeX Live distribution packaged for Ubuntu, Fedora or an alike system and the Danish language support hasn't been installed.

Comment: thank you very much!!! really kind of you. I have now update my linux and it worked :-)